# Scan over every other element of a tensor variable in Theano

Tags: numpy, parallel-processing, gpgpu, theano

it should produce something like:

```
input = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
output = scan_every_other(lambda x:x, input)
// output should be [1,3,5]
```

I have briefly read the [theano.scan tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/loop.html) but I didn't find what I'm looking for.
Thank you.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `theano.scan`. Just use ordinary index/slice notation as in numpy:

In numpy, if

```
input = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

then

```
print input[::2]
```

will display

```
[1, 3, 5]
```

In Theano, this can be achieved by doing the same thing:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt
input = tt.vector()
f = theano.function([input], input[::2])
print f([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```